# Combining 2 ctype.h functions into an IF in C

Tags: c

I am having trouble with the following line of code.

```
//check number of words
            if ((isblank(s[i]) != 0 && isblank(s[i+1] == 0)))
            words++;
```

I would like to count the number of "blanks" that is followed by a non-blank, but combining these 2 isblanks do not seem to count correctly. Could someone please help me out?

Comment: `isblank(s[i+1] == 0)` -> `isblank(s[i+1]) == 0`

Comment: You might also need to check what happens at the end of the string. Like is the count of `"hello "` 1 or 0

Comment: Could you provide the whole loop or at least the loop condition to see if you ain´t got undefined behavior accessing one element beyond the bounds of the array `s`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is a typo problem, your bracket is not in the correct place.

In this case the `isblank()` function get `TRUE` parameter if the `s[i+1]` is equal to 0, otherwise `FALSE`:

`isblank(s[i+1] == 0)`

I believe you wanted the to write the following:
`isblank(s[i+1]) == 0`

Comment: Thank you so much. I highly appreciate this. I missed the ) after defining the char. It works fine now.